# I have error when parse json code with volley in kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, android-volley, kotlin-android-extensions

I have com.android.volley.authfailureerror error in may code.how can i fix it?
my json link is:
http://shdesign.gigfa.com/json/json_kaghaz_divari.php
but i have a  error

```
class Gallery : AppCompatActivity() {
    val url = "http://shdesign.gigfa.com/json/json_kaghaz_divari.php"
    var images: ArrayList<Album> = ArrayList()
    private var locationItemAdapter: GalleryAdapter? = null
    private var recyclerView: RecyclerView? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery)
        val activity_gallery = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_gallery, null)
        setContentView(activity_gallery)
        //val mAdapter=GalleryAdapter(this,images)
        recyclerView=activity_gallery.actv_gallery_recyclerView as RecyclerView
        var mLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
        recyclerView!!.layoutManager = mLayoutManager
        //recyclerView.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)
        //recyclerView.adapter=mAdapter
        fetchImage()

    }
    fun fetchImage(){
        val pd=ProgressDialog(this)
        pd.setMessage("wait...")
        pd.setCancelable(false)
        pd.show()
       /* val req=JsonArrayRequest(url,Response.Listener<JSONArray>{
            Override fun onResponse(JSONArray_response){

        }
        }) */
          val oRequest = object : StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, Response.Listener {
            response ->
            pd.hide()

              try {
                  val locationArray = JSONArray(response)
                  images=ArrayList(locationArray.length())
                  for (i in 0 until locationArray.length()){
                      val loc = locationArray.get(i) as JSONObject


                      images.add(Album(
                           loc.getString("kid"),
                           loc.getString("kname"),
                           loc.getString("kcity")


                       ))

                  }
                  locationItemAdapter = GalleryAdapter(this,images)
                  recyclerView!!.setAdapter(locationItemAdapter)
              }catch (e:JSONException) {
                 e.printStackTrace()

              }

              },Response.ErrorListener { error ->
              Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Error: " + (error.toString()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              pd.hide()
          })  {
          }
            val requestQ = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)
        requestQ.add(oRequest)


          }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details as per the How to Create a [mcve] page. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I have not any error in my code but when I run my code , my json info do not load in my app and show this error:com.android.volley.authfailureerror